# Return an Async and Sync client from Build

Tags: java, asynchronous, design-patterns

I'm new to java design patterns and I'm trying to set up a build method that either returns an async client if the boolean *isAsync* is true and a sync client otherwise

```
public DGraphClient build() {
    if (isAsync) {
        return AsyncDGraphJavaClient.getInstance(host,port,user,pass);
    }
    return DGraphJavaClient.getInstance(host,port,user,pass);
}
```

This is what I would like my logic to be, but the two returns are not of the same type (one is an async client and the other a sync client). How can I accomplish what I want?

Comment: They are both subclasses of the returned type, so it will work OK.

Comment: Intellij tells me that it Found DGraphAsyncClient but requires DGraphClient

Comment: Then maybe DGraphAsyncClient doesn't extend (or implement) DGraphClient?

Comment: It does. Both classes AsyncDGraphJavaClient and DGraphJavaClient impliment DGraphCLient

Comment: Then you wouldn't be getting such an error message. Maybe you've got two similar-sounding classes (you've already mentioned two different classes in your question, DGraphAsyncClient and AsyncDGraphJavaClient) and only one of them implements DGraphClient. Or maybe you have the same-named class in a different package, and your code imports the wrong one.